# When importing a swig generated module, Python is complaining about missing delete method

Tags: python, c++, swig

We have a set of c++ classes wrapped by swig for python. When importing one of these classes in python, we're getting the following error message:

```
File ".../myobjects.py", line 176, in <module>
class RT(_object):
File ".../myobjects.py", line 187, in RT
\__swig_destroy__ = _myobjects.delete_RT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'delete_RT'
```

myobjects.py swig generated code of RT looks like this:

```
class RT(_object):
    __swig_setmethods__ = {}
    __setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: _swig_setattr(self, RT, name, value)
    __swig_getmethods__ = {}
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, RT, name)
    __repr__ = _swig_repr
    def __init__(self, *args):
        this = _myobjects.new_RT(*args)
        try: self.this.append(this)
        except: self.this = this
    def getName(self): return _myobjects.RT_getName(self)
    __swig_destroy__ = _myobjects.delete_RT
    __del__ = lambda self : None;
```

And the cxx file from which _myobjects.so is created has the following lines:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_delete_RT(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  RT *arg1 = (RT *) 0 ;
...
```

In short, all appears in order but we still get the python error.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks,

Tomer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure why this happened, but the Class just preceeding this one in the cxx file was included by two i files. Removing one inclusion fixed the issue.